# How to navigate from tab bar controller to other view controler and vice-versa

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs. I am using storyboard to make connections between them.

But the view controller in 4th tab has 3 buttons. Each button should lead to different `UIViewController`. Well the forward navigation is fine using segue. But facing problem in back navigation. If I am adding a back segue then I am losing the tab bar controls.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController as the root view controller of 4th UIViewController or not?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your view controller in 4th tab has 3 buttons. Each button should lead to different viewControllers, Each viewControllers(the one which you are wish to enter from the button) should be embedded in navigationController and add push segues to each button.